# Default value for bool in c#

Tags: c#, .net

```
public bool PrepaymentCalculating { get; set; }
```

So I declare a variable on one of my classes like that. I want this to default to 'null' and not false. Would I just need to make this a nullable boolean? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Would I just need to make this a nullable boolean?

Yes.

> Or is there a better way to do this?

No.

You can achieve this with

```
public bool? PrepaymentCalculating { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 5):

try

```
public bool? PrepaymentCalculating { get; set; }
```

Here's a post on [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

```
public bool? PrepaymentCalculating { get; set; }
```

will make it nullable.  Read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be null then you need to make it a nullable type.

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone else said, but I thought I'd add, what's your purpose here? It's not often that I want to *expose* a nullable bool, since this means that everything that uses this property must account for a possible null value.

But sometimes I want to know if it's been initialized or not in a given context, and if not, then use a value from somewhere else (e.g. to cascade property values). In this case you might want to use a pattern like this:

```
public bool PrepaymentCalculating { 
    get {
        if (_PrepaymentCalculating != null ) {
            return (bool)_PrepaymentCalculating;
        } else {
            return somethingElse; // bool
        }
    }
    set {
      _PrepaymentCalculating = value;
    }
} protected bool? _PrepaymentCalculating =null;
```

Answer (score -1):

bool can't be null. The default is probably false (but don't quote me on that).

If you want it to be null, then yes you have to declare it as nullable.

Comment: Yes, the default value is `false`. Think of zero for false (and non-zero for one) and note that the default value for value types just zeros the structure out. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx.