# How can I initialize a 2-d C# array to all of the same value?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

What I want to do is described in the comment below. How can I do, efficiently?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
class Solution {
    static void Main(String[] args) {
        int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        bool[][] flags = new bool[26][n]; // I want this to be a 26 x n array of false values
        for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
        {
            string line = Console.WriteLine();
            for(int i = 0; i < line.Length; ++i)
                flags[(int)line[i] - (int)'a'] = true;
        }
        int gems = flags.Count(arr => arr.Count(j => j == true) == arr.Length);       
        Console.WriteLine
    }
}
```

Comment: The array is already initialized to all `false`. It's part of the language specification. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15300089/56778 for the details.

Comment: If you want all the value to be false, why are you setting them to true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default value for bool in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996582/default-value-for-bool-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are confused between [Multidimensional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) arrays and [Jagged Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) (Array of Arrays).

If you are looking for 2d Array, you could simply do this.

```
bool[,] flags = new bool[26,n]; 
//or
bool[,] flags = new bool[,]; 
bool[,] flags = new bool[26,];
```

If it is Jagged Arrays, you could do this.

```
bool[][] flags1 = new bool[26][];
flags1[0] = new bool[n];  // since you want n elements 
flags1[1] = new bool[n];
...

// initialization
flags1[0] = new bool[] {true, false};
flags1[1] = new bool[] {false};
```

Answer (score 7):

LINQ should work well for your goal:

```
bool[][] flags = Enumerable.Range(0, 26).Select(_ => Enumerable.Repeat(true, n).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Or as Jim Mischel said:

```
bool[][] flags = Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Repeat(true, n).ToArray(), 26).ToArray();
```

But the first example uses less memory becuase the `Select` method doesn't re-define `Enumerable.Repeat(true, n).ToArray()` as it goes through the items.

Comment: Can be simplified to `flags = Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Repeat(true, n).ToArray(), 26).ToArray();`

Comment: `flags = Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Repeat(true, n).ToArray(), 26).ToArray();`
is incorrect as it will create the "inner" array only once and then will initialize "rows" with a reference to it. So, when you modify, say [0][0], the you'll see the same value in [1][0],.. [n][0].